# How do i convert a image as a string to PNG file

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [wPaint](https://github.com/websanova/wPaint) to allow users to draw their own image.  I send the resulting image as a string to the server as a string which begins with

> data:image/png;base64,

I tried the two approaches below but with both the approaches i'm not able to store the image.

Approach 1

```
String imageData = parameterParser.getStringParameter("image", ""); 
byte[] imgByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageData.getBytes());
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/arvind/Desktop/test.png");
fileOutputStream.write(imgByteArray);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

In this case the file is written but doesn't show the image. However, when i remove the file extension i get the string that was sent to the server (i.e. whatever is in imageData).

Approach 2

```
String imageData = parameterParser.getStringParameter("image", ""); 
byte[] imgByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageData.getBytes());
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgByteArray);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File("/home/arvind/Desktop/test.png"));
```

The BufferedImage bImageFromConvert is null so I get an exception (IllegalArgumentException) when the file is created.

The Base64 class is from the apache commons codec library and is version 1.2.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how the image is converted as a string?

Comment: in the plugin wPaint (which is actually a jQuery plugin), there is a function to convert the image to a string.  the string is converted correctly becuase if you assign an img src with the same string on the client side, the image is shown.

Comment: then you need to convert it back into bytes with the same plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially I had sent the data to the server using the following code.

```
    $.ajax({
        url : '/campaign/holiImageUpload.action',
        type : 'POST',
        data : "image=" + $("#wPaint2").wPaint("image")
        success :function(data){
        }
    });
```

Now i'm sending the data to the server using the following code

```
var imgData = $("#wPaint2").wPaint("image");
    $.ajax({
        url : '/campaign/holiImageUpload.action',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {image : imgData},
        success :function(data){
        }
    });
```

In the server side this is the final code :

```
String imageData = parameterParser.getStringParameter("image", "");

    try {
        imageData = imageData.substring(22);
        byte[] imgByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageData.getBytes());
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgByteArray);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("/home/arvind/Desktop/test.png"));
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStrackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That did the trick for me, just a small correction: instead of Base64.decodeBase64(imageData.getBytes()), i used: Base64.getDecoder().decode((imageData.getBytes()))

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to decode `data:image/png'base64` along with your Base64 encoded data? You will want to remove that from the input string before you decode the Base64 data into image bytes.

Also, you don't want to decode the string as bytes... just as a string.

Comment: can you share some code snippet? i'm not too sure what apis will allow me to write an image file using string as input itself.

Comment: The base64 data is a string-encoding for byte data. When you decode the base64-encoded string, it becomes a byte array again containing the data for the image. Once you strip off the non-encoded data as suggested in my answer.

Comment: have already tried that too (i.e. imageData = imageData.substring(22) .. that didn't do the trick.

Comment: I would suggest providing a string dump of a small image request so that we can see exactly what is being read by the backend.

Comment: here you go - [the full input to the java code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EZ4SNr8LChQW1HjTvL39PzV_6a31I963m7vRiWMpnqc/edit?pli=1)